# How to git-diff a single, staged file with same file in other branch

Tags: git, branch, git-diff

If I understand correctly, if I do

```
git diff master devel ./my_file
```

I get the diff between the two HEADs of the branches.  However, if I have made changes in, say, `master` and staged them, I thought I could get the diff between the unstaged file and the corresponding file in the other branch with

```
$ git diff --cached master devel ./my_file
```

but I get the following error:

```
usage: git diff [<options>] [<commit> [<commit>]] [--] [<path>...]
```

So what is the correct way to get the diff between staged changes in a file and the corresponding file in another branch?

Comment: You could commit the staged files and then compare them?

Comment: Yes, but it would nice to be able to check the file before it goes into a commit.

Comment: Why bother? A commit can be discarded (much like a stash). You can treat commits as temporary if you want.

Comment: Making a commit just to check the stage defeats the purpose of having a stage.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I misread stage as stash...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following syntax:

```
git diff --cached devel -- my_file.ext
```

This should compare `my_file.ext` as it is at the HEAD of the `devel` branch against the current stage in `master` (assuming you run this command on the `master` branch).

There is a lot going on in this command, but note that `--cached` does not refer to `devel`, which is a commit where the concept of stage does not apply.  Instead, `--cached` refers to the file `my_file.ext` which follows the `--` separator.

This command corresponds to the following pattern from the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…​]
```

Here `devel` is the commit and `my_file.ext` is the file path.

Comment: Sorry for having  written 'unstaged' rather than 'staged' in the orignal question.  This works, but which case is it from the manpage?  The synopisis and description there don't seem to cover branches.

Comment: @loris Check my updated answer, it does match to the Git manual.

Comment: You're right, although I find it a bit confusing, since my understanding is that a branch is a reference to a commit rather than being an actual commit.

Comment: Git's manual is somewhat loose as technical documentation goes.  As for the syntax, a branch name can be used to mean the HEAD commit of that branch, e.g. in a rebase.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I'm including @Tim's answer to my original question, which was about getting the diff for an unstaged as opposed to staged file relative to another branch.  His solution was `git diff devel:my_file -- my_file`. I haven't spotted the syntax with the colon in the man pages, but it is described here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec